# Delete multiple records from multiple tables based on child table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to delete multiple table data with an unique id.

I need to delete that table data if child table does not exist.

I tried `isnull` and if null option but its not working:-

```
SELECT * FROM carbrand 
INNER JOIN carmodel 
INNER JOIN carversion 
WHERE 
(
     (carmodel.brandid = carbrand.recid) OR 
     (carmodel.brandid = '')
) 
AND 
(
     (carversion.brandid = carbrand.recid) OR 
     (carversion.brandid = '')
 ) 
 AND carbrand.recid = 17
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the condition of the JOIN on each table using ON.  If you want JOINS which may not return a match, use LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN will only return a record where there is a match...

```
SELECT * FROM carbrand 
LEFT JOIN carmodel ON carmodel.brandid = carbrand.recid
LEFT JOIN carversion ON carversion.brandid = carbrand.recid
WHERE carbrand.recid = 17
```

With LEFT JOIN, all values from that table will be null if the record is not found.

Comment: i need to get both output null and not null condition that's the problem i faced.

Comment: If you remove the 'is null' conditions above, see what that gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code

```
SELECT * FROM carbrand 
INNER JOIN carmodel 
INNER JOIN carversion 
WHERE 
(
    (carmodel.brandid = carbrand.recid) OR 
    (carmodel.brandid IS NULL)
) 
AND 
(
    (carversion.brandid = carbrand.recid) OR 
    (carversion.brandid IS NULL)
) 
AND carbrand.recid = 17
```